# Project Euler #1 - Multiples of 3 and 5 - First Program

Tags: c#, beginner, programming-challenge

Taking a problem from the website, "[Project Euler #1](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1)", I have created my first C# program. The problem I have used is as follows:

> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
>
> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

The program I have made:

```
using System;

namespace _5_multiples
{
    public class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            int currentNumber = 1000;
            int allSum = 0;

            currentNumber = currentNumber - 1;
            while (currentNumber > 0)
            {
                if (currentNumber % 3 == 0)
                {
                    allSum = allSum + currentNumber;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (currentNumber % 5 == 0)
                    {
                        allSum = allSum + currentNumber;
                    }
                }
                currentNumber = currentNumber - 1;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(allSum);
        }
    }
}
```

I understand there is probably a lot to improve - this is my first C# program after all. I did run into a few problems such as referencing non static members from a static context and no suitable entry method. Rather than finding a definitive fix, the solution I implemented was more of a workaround; hence why I feel there may be a lot to improve.

`namespace _5_multiples` - this doesn't look right? Name of the program is actually `3_5_multiples` - perhaps a badly chosen name?

Anyway, please let me know on anything that could be improved.

Comment: You should use the `for` loop.

Comment: It is a good practice to leave a question open for a day or two to get a full range of answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I would change:

- I'd use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop here: `for (int currentNumber = 999; currentNumber > 0; currentNumber--)`. This keeps all loop-related things grouped together. Loop bodies can be skipped or broken out of, so if code that must be executed every cycle is put at the end of a loop body it's easily broken when the loop body grows more complex and someone adds a `continue` or `break` in there.
- Actually, there is no need to count down - the result will be the same either way. Counting up is often a little easier to understand: `for (int currentNumber = 0; currentNumber < 1000; currentNumber++)`. Note that using `<` here means you don't need to decrement `currentNumber` by one before the loop starts.
- You can write `a += b` instead of `a = a + b` (the same goes for various other operators).
- `else { if { .. } }` can be simplified to `else if { ... }`.
- Though in this case, a single if statement is sufficient: `if (currentNumber % 3 == 0 || currentNumber % 5 == 0) { ... }`. The 'or' operator (`||`) short-circuits if the first expression is true, so if a number can be divided by 3 it won't also try to divide it by 5.
- C# naming conventions typically write class, method and namespace names in `PascalCase`.

Regarding your questions:

- Static things belong to a class, non-static things belong to instances of that class. Classes are to instances what blueprints are to actual buildings. Trying to access a non-static (instance) members from a static context is like trying to open a door on a blueprint. The blueprint doesn't contain any real doors, only actual buildings do.
- Programs need a place to start executing, and in C# the starting point is a static `Main` method. Putting everything in there is fine for a small program like this.
- Identifier names in C# cannot start with a number, so `3_5_multiples` isn't a valid name. I'd probably use `EulerProblem1` or something like that here.
- Namespaces are useful for organizing larger programs (namespaces to classes are a bit like folders to files). The root namespace of a project is usually the name of that project itself, and child namespaces often correspond to folders.

EDIT: Part of the fun on Project Euler is coming up with more efficient solutions. Can you find a way to solve this without checking every number below 1000?

Answer (score 0):

I have edited my program following the advice given on this thread:

```
using System;

namespace EulerProblemOne
{
    public class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            int allSum = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number...");
            int inputNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            inputNumber -= 1;

            for (int currentNumber = inputNumber; currentNumber > 0; currentNumber--)
                if ((currentNumber % 3 == 0) || (currentNumber % 5 == 0))
                {
                    allSum += currentNumber;
                }
            Console.WriteLine(allSum); 
        }
    }
}
```

I now have the following:

- Renamed the program so that it no longer starts with a number.
- The number to check under can now be inputted by the user and not a fixed literal.
- A for loop is used instead of a while loop.
- IF statements have been combined into a single IF statement using OR.
- Arithmetic lines now use add/subtract and assign in a single operator.

Comment: You could also have loop go forward as in `for (int currentNumber = 1; currentNumber <= inputNumber; currentNumber++)`.  The conditional could be changed to `<` if you did not issue `inputNumber -= 1`.

Comment: You should always put the logic of a `for` loop in a code block (i.e. surround it with `{` and `}`.  This will prevent you from very nasty bugs. Image what would happen if you put a `Console.WriteLine()` on the line before your if-statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the loop counter for currentNumber
Can use an or for divisible

```
public static int Numbers(int toNumber)
{
    int allSum = 0;
    for (int i = 3; i < toNumber; i++)
    {
        if (i % 3 == 0 | i % 5 == 0)
        {
            allSum += i;
        }
    }
    Debug.WriteLine(allSum);
    return allSum;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    using System;

namespace _5_multiples
{
    public class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            int currentNumber = 1000;
            int allSum = 0;

            currentNumber = currentNumber - 1;
            while (currentNumber > 0)
            {
                if ( (currentNumber % 3 == 0) | (currentNumber % 5 == 0))
                {
                    allSum = allSum + currentNumber;
                }
                currentNumber = currentNumber - 1;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(allSum);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my advice, you didn't need both -if-, only one is necessary.

Comment: `|` is a binary operator, `||` is the boolean one, which should be used here. And are you sure your second example is working properly (apart from the compile errors)? Some numbers can be divided by both 3 and 5.

Comment: It was more about giving the OP an idea of improvement than giving you a perfect answer. But yeah you're right about the fact that some are both multiples of 5 and 3 I'll edit my post :). For the question of | or || we don't really care since we are comparing ones or zeros.

Comment: Binary `&` instead of boolean `&&`, more variable name typo's, `currentNumber5` is still unassigned before use, and since `currentNumber3` and `currentNumber5` go down at different 'speeds' they won't be equal, so the result still isn't correct. Personally, I don't mind, but the OP is new to C#, so showing them broken and incorrect code isn't very helpful.

Comment: Tip: if creating a project in Visual Studio is too much effort, then tools like Linqpad can be useful to quickly verify snippets of code like this.

Comment: I don't usually do C#, I'm more of a C guy, but anyway, if you find other mistakes please feel free to edit my code. I don't have enough time to do it.

Comment: I really tried to understand your second approach but failed. After fixing the syntax errors and running it on ideone it produced a wrong result.